# Pandas Merge: How to create a counter field in the format of "Group Count - Subgroup Cumcount" to better mark the many-to-one join rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a data frame that is the left join result of the two following dataframes:

```
e1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Hour': [9, 10, 11]})
e2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'Price': [25, 32, 33, 110, 108, 112]})

ex = pd.merge(e1, e2, on = 'ID', how = 'left')
```

The dataframe looks like this:

[image: ex]

My desired result is this:

[image: desired result]

Right now my process of doing this is quite lengthy:

```
es1 = pd.DataFrame(ex.ID.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop = True))
es1['new_count'] = es1.index + 1

ex['sub_group_count'] = ex.groupby(['ID']).cumcount()+1
ex_m = pd.merge(ex, es1, on='ID', how = 'left')

ex_m['many_to_one_id'] = ex_m.new_count.astype(str) + '-' + ex_m.sub_group_count.astype(str)
ex_m.loc[ex_m.duplicated(subset= ['ID']), ['ID', 'Hour']] = np.nan
```

Basically I manually created the group counter field and sub group cumcount field, and then I joined them together to get the 'many_to_one_id' field. I wonder if there's a better and more Pythonic way to achieve this.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Five lines to create something that's heavily customized and very case-specific seems reasonable. Explicitly introducing NaN to a DataFrame is weird, but you say that's required. This feels like you've lost sight of the real goal and instead asked about an implementation that doesn't do what you want.
You might want to consider your overall goal in constructing this DF: Does the "many_to_one_id" field actually matter for your use-case? Are you just trying to isolate a set of Prices for each id? Are you constructing this DF to be used in some other filter / join?

Comment: @SarahMesser Hey Sarah, thanks for the feedback. The end result is a requested exhibit format. I guess the reason behind the duplicate rows being null is that it would be visually more prominent to see the row with multiple joined records. The "many_to_one_id" field exists for the same reason: part of the exhibit format. This DF won't be used in any further operation (that I know of)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumcount` create the additional key

```
e2['key']=e2.groupby('ID').cumcount()
e1['key']=e1.groupby('ID').cumcount()
ex = pd.merge(e2, e1, on = ['ID', 'key'], how = 'left')
ex
Out[15]: 
  ID  Price  key  Hour
0  A     25    0   9.0
1  B     32    0  10.0
2  B     33    1   NaN
3  C    110    0  11.0
4  C    108    1   NaN
5  C    112    2   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this succinct answer. But could you add something to make the key field look like `1-2`, `1-3` instead of just `2`, `3`, so that the left and right cumcount number can coexist like in my desired result?

Comment: @BowenLiu when you combine the ID with the Key it is same as your many_to_one key ~ ex['manytoone']=ex.ID + '_' + ex.key.astype(str)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Good point. In my real data the ID field is made up of repulsively long numbers. Maybe I shall post this as a new question: is a better way to create a separate ID field where each value maps to the original ID field? Back to the original question, if the dataframe I have is already joined like `ex` in my description (in my case it's a left joined result pulled from SQL), is there any way to get my desired result? Thanks again,